# Change Variables in inner class

Tags: android

So, my problem is that... I'm a beginner with java and android.
What I want to do is let the boolean "active" become "true", when the first button is clicked (the thread is necessary for an other part of the code)
then, when the second button is clicked & active == true, Player1Score becomes +1.
So the problem is that i can't use non-final variables in the thread & my onClickListener, but I can't use final variables because i need to change them in the code.
If possible please give beginner-friendly answers, thanks!

```
    [...]
    boolean active;
    int Player1Score, Player2Score;

    Player1Score = 0;
    Player2Score = 0;


    Button button_launch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_launch);
    button_launch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            [...]

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    [...]

                    active = true;

                }

            }).start();

        }
    });

    [...]

    Button button_player1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button_player1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(active == true){

                Player1Score++;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean.  I think it will de exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can avoid this is to use another variable to use inside your listener

```
final boolean variable = active;
Button button_player1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button_player1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(variable == true){

            Player1Score++;
        }
```

Comment: That's great, but how do I change the original "active" value In the other thread?

Answer (score 0):

One more method is to make make your boolean value "volatile" i.e its a keyword in java which makes the threads to read the value of that particular variable from main memory and not cache their values.
For eg. volatile boolean active=false;

Comment: is there a way to do this to ints? (I already had an answer to that question, but thanks)

Comment: it can be applied to ints also(only variables no methods).